# Build Only for managed code

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

Is there any way to avoid building all the references of a dll in order to simulate a "Build Only" for managed dlls?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the file `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`, you'll find that building of referenced projects inside the target `ResolveProjectReferences`is conditional on the property test `'$(BuildPassReferences)' == 'true'`.

If you set this property to `false` on MSBuild invocaton, references will not be rebuild:

```
msbuild ... /properties:BuildPassReferences=false,...
```

Note that this is not a supported feature, and that your compilation will likely genuinely fail if outputs of the referenced projects do not exist. Unlike C++ using include files to resolve external references, managed compilation needs existing reference DLLs.

So the answer is yes it is possible, not supported, and a clear step on the way into a trouble, unless the end you are trying to achieve is very specific and narrow.